# Is there a general approach to identify maven coordinates to add as project dependencies starting from the desired set of classes/framework?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

Given my experience with Maven, I have found that sometimes adding dependencies (thru coordinates) to the projects is an "art" of Googling or replicating an existing project that is close to what you are trying to do. Some well known frameworks as Spring have a lot of examples on how to do this (maybe a lot for the most popular modules, and sometimes not that much for specialization modules).

I'm interested in hearing the recommendations about how much can this process be generalized. Let's say I find framework `A`, or a utility class `B` that I would like to use. Having these as inputs, can I do a particular search in the Maven repository or use a Maven plugin to identify potential matches that contain `B`?

Answer (score 2):

YOu can search in http://grepcode.com/ or  http://search.maven.org, for this last one, click on 'Advanced search' and then you can search by GroupId, ArtfactId or className.

Then, once you know the GroupId, ArtfactId and version you need, add it to your pom.xml.